# no mail default in form

Tags: python, django, forms

I am using a form django and I want values that are already defined in my model. But the default value for mail is not showing up in the form. Why?

forms.py

```
class ForeningForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Forening
        exclude = ['ordf','kass','adress']
        fields=['fname','fphone','mail','homepage','direktansk','anslutenannat',\
                'anteckningar','uppdaterad']
```

model.py:

```
class Forening(Model):
    
    fname=CharField(default='missing',max_length=100)
    ordf=OneToOneField(Person,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='ordf')
    kass=OneToOneField(Person,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='ka')
    fphone=PhoneField(default='9999999999')
    adress=OneToOneField(Adress,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='ad')
    mail=EmailField(default='missing@gmail.com')
    homepage=TextField(max_length=400,default='www.homepage.com')
    direktansk=BooleanField(default=False)
    anslutenannat=BooleanField(default=False)
    anteckningar=TextField(max_length=500,default='missing')
    uppdaterad=DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'förening: ' + self.fname

    class Meta:
        ordering=('fname','ordf')
```

views.py:

```
class Fcreate(CreateView):

    form_class=ForeningForm
    template_name='kammem/create.html'

    def form_valid(self,form)

        fname=form.cleaned_data['fname']
        venue=form.cleaned_data['venue']
        fphone=form.cleaned_data['fphone']
        mail=form.cleaned_data['mail']
        homepage=form.cleaned_data['homepage']
        direktansk=form.cleaned_data['direktansk']
        anslutenannat=form.cleaned_data['anslutenannat']
        antekningar=form.cleaned_data['antekningar']
        uppdaterad=form.cleaned_data['uppdaterad']
```

Answer (score 0):

Default is not displayed because field value isn't required by model (since it have the default value it won't be set to blank even if user havent filled this field). Probably the easiest solution for your issue will be overriding [get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form) method with using [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values) value for field added to form instantiation call:

```
class Fcreate(CreateView):

form_class=ForeningForm
template_name='kammem/create.html'

...

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        if form_class is None:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form_kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
        form_kwargs.update(
            {'initial' : {'email': 'missing@gmail.com'}}
        )
        form = form_class(**form_kwargs)
        return form
```

Comment: where do you wanna put it? in views?

Comment: @JonasFredriksson see updated answer. You need to override method that return instantiated form and pass initial value during instantiation.

Comment: I got an type error when trying: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: hm, ok, according to code source form class may not be passed directly to method - https://github.com/django/django/blob/7c18b22e2fa70aa8dcfadb33beb17933abdf7ee4/django/views/generic/edit.py#L29. See updated answer.

Comment: ok, error is gone but no default message. I have to dig in to this. Strange that such a simple thing has to be that complicated. thanks for all the answers